# Better .NET SDK support - Canon or Nikon?

Tags: c#, wia, photography

Need to do a remote image capture from a "prosumer" camera into a `C#/.NET` app (for capturing pics at a higher resolution and more control than a webcam).

Any advantage for Canon vs. Nikon remote capture SDK's? Is one better supported than another? Looking for a developer perspective before embarking on this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at both SDK's when I was picking out cameras.  I ended up going with the Canon EOS 50D and their EDSDK.  Canon has a wrapper class in their code with all the P/Invoke ready for you to use.  That was the primary reason I used it.  Some of the P/Invoke types are a little odd.  I had issues with figuring out some object reference types needed to be casted to some internal structures...  Lot's of trial and error.  Eventually I got it to work, and it works well.  I have live image capture and static image capture working for it.

I'm sorry I cannot speak for Nikon's SDK.  I just chose Canon's because the P/Invoke was already there.  The downside to EDSDK is it only works with the EOS line.

Here is some more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710352/snapping-pictures-from-windows-c-canon-sdk-vs-ptp-or-mtp).

Comment: I started Canon.Eos.Framework https://github.com/esskar/Canon.Eos.Framework just today. It is far from finished, but talking a picture works like a charme. :-)